# Splitting DC Supply Rail with High Output Currents

Tags: power-supply, high-current, split

I'm currently working on a audio amplifier circuit that requires split supply rails. I have a wall converter that can supply 19V, and I ideally want to be able to create a ± 12V supply rail out of the 19V and still be able to output somewhere around 3amps. Does anyone know an easy solution? Most solutions I've found can only supply up to 500mA. 
If it's much easier, I can also just split the 19V to ±9.5V. But again, I have not been able to find a circuit or IC that can output up to 3amps.

Comment: I would NOT use a wall wart as an audio amplifier power rail supply without additional conditioning. Their transformers often have as bad as (or worse) 30% regulation. The fact that you feel you need \$\pm 12V\$ also is very suggestive that you should seriously consider developing the power supply itself (or buy one with both rails included and the required current compliances.) Looks like you are considering a \$4\Omega\$ speaker support, too. At \$18W?\$ Would you be willing to consider ICs? What about single-supply but bridge-tied load? Expand your question?

Comment: I am already using a PC PSU and was hoping to decrease the size of hardware by using a smaller power supply. After doing a bit testing, I realized that I would only need about 800mA from the -12V supply and about 2.5A from the +12V line. Another ±24V DC power brick that I found can supply up to 4.5A and I've added various bypass capacitors on the supply lines in my circuit, so I think I should be fine using the brick as a supply. Is there an IC that can create a -12V rail with 1A output capability?

Comment: There are ICs and there are complete modules to do that. Do you know how to use Digikey to search for these? (It seems odd to me that your supply current requirements for an audio amplifier are so imbalanced as you mentioned. But that's your business, I suppose.)

Answer (score 2):

If you could do what you want, you would win the Nobel Prize. Your supply puts out 19 volts at 500 ma, which is a power level of 9.5 watts. If you could use that to produce +/- 12 volts at 3 amps, a single side would produce 12 volts at 3 amps, or 36 watts. So you could then use 9.5 of those watts to feed the input of your converter, and have 26.5 watts for free. Of course, you could then cascade converters to run your house, run an electric car, or anything else a perpetual motion machine is good for.

As you might guess, this is not going to happen.

Comment: You forgot to mention sending some to Africa and saving the continent from poverty

Answer (score 0):

This becomes a make/buy decision.    I suggest you shop for the best bipolar +/- PSU to match the bass current you need with regulated outputs and line filters to prevent hum.

Otherwise hum or switching regulator noise will result from unregulated or regulated wall worts with dual sources for both polarities. Consider surplus PC PSU's with adequate -12V current.

To make a floating 24V supply into a bipolar supply requires a high current linear amp with V/2 reference and output gets grounded. So the driver is inefficient and carries all the speaker current.  But if you used a single 24V supply with 2 bridge amps (differential) per speaker then the speakers will be at 12Vdc on either side. or use 12 V supply with differential like many 22W car radios.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what you mean by an easy solution though...

It is possible, yes, but your power supply(the 19V one) has to be able to supply nearly 2 ampéres and above....Because there is no such thing as a 100% effecient system. What I did was to make a mini power supply that changes your 19V to 12V dual rail using a regulator + 555 combination to drive a MOSFET to drive a switch mode supply transformer. 
Search it up and you'll see what I mean. You have to experiment around and blow some stuff up;; 
Murphy's Law always holds in all things :')